# In flutter, Share a link using Share Plus then page moves to status bar and status become hide

Tags: android, flutter, dart, share, share-plus

I am using the Share package so that when I click on the icon I can share the link but the page moves to the status bar, this issue comes to android only.

Screenshots: (In the second screenshot, the title of the page moved in the status bar)

**Before Share**

[image]

**After Share**

[image]

```html
class FeesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FeesPage({super.key});

  Future<void> share() async {
    await Share.share("Example share", subject: "Test subject");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Share text and link'),
                onPressed: share,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Share local file'),
                onPressed: share,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping your Scaffold with SafeArea once...

Comment: @KaranMehta I tried, but still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue properly because I'm not able to understand what else did you meant?

Comment: when we click on the button to share the link, then share sheet open from the bottom but page moves to in the status bar means app bar moves in the status bar.

Comment: I found no such issue when tested this code on Pixel 4 API 31 emulator.